# Conjugate Gradient method convergence

Tags: haskell, matrix, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix

I have written both Gauss Seidel and Conjugate Gradient iterative algorithms for solving matricies in Haskell (but this question is related to the methods not so much the language). My understanding was that both of these algorithms should have similar convergence characteristics and that the CG method should be faster in most cases. I have run many tests on symmetric positive definite matrices from http://math.nist.gov/MatrixMarket/ and I can almost never get the CG alg. to converge, while the GS almost always does. I cannot find any symmetric positive definite matrices with an accompanying right hand side vector for testing purposes online, so I have been just arbitrarily creating my own RHS (maybe this is part of the problem?). I can get the CG method to converge if I use (transpose A) * A instead of A in Ax = b, which is just forcing the matrix to be symmetric. I have included the CG code here. It will obviously not compile as-is. If someone needs it functioning to help, I will post it all. It is working correctly for the simple example here [(Similar question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12027026/incremental-conjugate-gradient-algorithm) that came from [(Pseudocode and example)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method). Is there something I'm missing regarding Conjugate Gradient vs. Gauss Seidel Convergence criteria? Can anyone point me in the right direction to get this working? Thanks.

```
conjGrad :: (Floating a, Ord a, Show a) => a -> SpMCR a -> SpVCR a -> SpVCR a -> (SpVCR a, Int)
conjGrad tol mA b x0 = loop x0 r0 r0 rs0 1
  where r0  = b - (mulMV mA x0)        
        rs0 = dot r0 r0
        loop x r p rs i
          | (varLog "residual = " $ sqrt rs') < tol = (x',i)          
          | otherwise                               = loop x' r' p' rs' (i+1)
          where mAp = mulMV mA p
                alpha = rs / (dot p mAp)
                x' = x + (alpha .* p)
                r' = r - (alpha .* mAp)
                rs' = dot r' r'
                beta = rs' / rs
                p'  = r' + (beta .* p)



(.*) :: (Num a) => a -> SpVCR a -> SpVCR a
(.*) s v = fmap (s *) v
```

**EDIT :** Sure enough, I failed to account for the fact that the MM file format only includes the lower diagonal of a symmetric matrix. Thanks. Now the algorithm converges but seems to take more iterations than it should. My understanding was that CG should always converge with a number of iterations less than the matrix order, when using exact arithmetic. Would the fact that were working with floating point (Double) make such a big difference (1.5 - 2 x the matrix order being the iterations required to reasonably converge) ?

**Follow Up:** For anyone who might stumble upon this, it turns out most of my problem was related to the matrices that I was using for the tests. It seems they were rather ill-conditioned for solving using the CG algorithm. Simple preconditioning helped in some cases.

Comment: "I can get the CG method to converge if I...which is just forcing the matrix to be symmetric." Isn't `A` already symmetric?

Comment: I thought so, that's part of my confusion. This is the matrix http://math.nist.gov/MatrixMarket/data/Harwell-Boeing/bcsstruc2/bcsstk14.html. I just noticed it's not diagonal dominate. I thought this was a requirement for convergence of Gauss Seidel, but not CG. Maybe that's the problem. If so, it seems that CG is only of use for a very specific class of matrix.

Comment: CG requires symmetric positive definite (spd) matrices for convergence. Gauss-Seidel is only guaranteed to converge for diagonally dominant and spd matrices.

Comment: Ar you sure you read in the matrices correctly? In the files offered for download, only nonzero entries on or below the main diagonal are specified, you may have forgotten to make it symmetric upon reading. Check whether `transpose A == A` after reading in.

Answer (score 1):

You can answer your second question by using an exact library with floating such as CReal from here: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/numbers or getting rid of your logging (which I think is what introduces the floating constraint) and just using the rationals from Data.Ratio.

This will of course be terribly slow. But it should let you investigate the impact of floating point approximation on convergence.

Comment: Thanks, I had not thought of trying that.